# How to run CICS on Java EE server other than websphere?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, glassfish, cobol, cics

I am wondering if / how I could get rid of websphere Java EE server to run an application that uses CICS to connect COBOL programs (mainly for easyness of use and to use open-source software).

CICS seems to be part of Java EE, but for instance, I can't find anyway of installing the connectors provided by IBM in Glashfish or TomEE.

Did anyone managed to run such application outside of WAS?

Comment: Yap, but you always fall back to IBM website... I can't find anyone who actually did it

Comment: Well, I found a couple of suggestions that seem to be without Websphere. I don't know what CICS you have. You could put in a PMR to IBM to see what they can suggest anyway.

Answer (score 1):

From the [CICS Transaction Gateway family](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/cics-ctg/) of products, the z/OS and Multiplatforms flavours include JCA resource adapters for Java EE-certified application servers.

Users of Java EE application servers other than those levels of WebSphere Application Server explicitly supported, need to successfully deploy the provided Install Veritifion Test (IVT) EAR file in order for support entitlement with that application server. Further details are available in the product information centers, starting with the [Java EE application servers](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cicstgzo/v9r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.cics.tg.zos.doc%2Fctgzos%2Fccl11ssw.ide6.html) topic.

For more information on the CICS TG family of products, refer to the IBM Redbook Solution Guide: *Flexible, High-Performing, Security-Rich, and Scalable Connectivity with CICS Transaction Gateway Products*, available at: ibm.biz/cicstg-sg